# where can i see the registered new field for posts using register_meta() ?

Tags: metabox

Where we can see the registered new field using

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_sample_meta' );

function register_my_sample_meta() {
  register_meta( 'post', 'my_registered_meta', 'my_sanitize_callback', '__return_false' );
}
```

I have checked the post edit page, can't see any additional field there. 
is it not visible in post edit page, where i can see this field.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have the custom fields option checked in the "screen options"

Comment: I have checked the custom fields option checked in the "screen options", but the registered meta field is not visible in admin panel. where i can modify the data in the meta field ?

Comment: Hi, if the field is registered , it will show up at the bottom of the post edit screen